# \rowcolor from colortbl package stopped working inside 'longtabu' environment

Tags: tabu, colortbl

## Problem description

After a recent system upgrade on a Debian testing machine with TeXLive 2018, a `\rowcolor` command inside a `\begin{longtabu}` environment no longer works.

Package versions according to `texdoc`:

- `colortbl` package: 2018/12/12
- `tabu` package: 2019/01/12

## Minimal (non-)working example (MWE)

Compile the following example with a single run of `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}% Required for \rowcolor
\usepackage{longtable}% Required for tabu package's 'longtabu' environment
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

% \rowcolor works as expected in a regular 'tabular' environment
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  foo                & bla\\
  \rowcolor{red} bla & foo
\end{tabular}

% \rowcolor no longer works (since recently) in a 'longtabu' environment
\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth {ll}%
  foo                & bla\\
  \rowcolor{red} bla & foo
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

A slightly more complex example used to produce the expected result (ie, a colored row also in the second example using `longtabu`) until about a month ago. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: See https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu. Read the readme there and check the issue list. If your issue is new (which I doubt, imho it is already known), add it.

Comment: Looks like it could be a duplicate of https://github.com/tabu-fixed/tabu/issues/13 - thanks, Ulrike!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is reported issue with the package